# Maven surefire configuration for separating test into unit and integration tests fail

Tags: java, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a project which contain unit and integration tests.
These tests are already split into unit and integration tests while using different class as suites.

How can I configure surefire to execute unit tests during phase "test" and integration test during phase "integration-Test".

Here is my current configuration:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/Test*.java</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/*Test.java</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/*Test*.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unit-test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/CoreUnitTests.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/CoreIntegrationTests.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

With this configuration no tests will be executed but if I remove the "excludes" all tests are executed in phase "test" and not only the unit tests.

---

**Update - Solution**

With the explanation of Adam Michalik I was able to solve the problem.
Instead of overriding default-test I skip these tests because id "unit-test" is better than "default-test" for my unit tests
Here is the final configuration of the pom:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-test</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unit-test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/CoreUnitTests.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/CoreIntegrationTests.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rule of thumb: `excludes` override `includes`. So, taking the `unit-test` execution as an example, your configuration tells Surefire to:

- first of all, only include `**/CoreUnitTests.java`
- but from that, exclude `**/Test*.java`, `**/Test.java` and `**/*Test*.java` - that exclusion list covers `CoreUnitTests.java`, so nothing is executed

Similarly for the `integration-test` execution.

So, to **only** run `CoreUnitTests` in the `test` phase and `CoreIntegrationTests` in the `integration-test` phase, is should be enough to configure the `includes` as you did and do not define any `excludes` anywhere. That is however not good enough, because, as you observed, all tests are run by the default Surefire execution called `default-test`, which, by default configuration, picks up all classes suffixed with `Test`. To work around this, you can either turn off that default execution by reconfiguring it

```
<execution>
    <id>default-test</id>
    <configuration>
        <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

or rename your `unit-test` execution to `default-test` (that will save a few milliseconds of your build time, because in the end you'll only invoke Surefire twice, not three times just to skip the default execution).